# How do I keep the 2nd <code> styled inside a <p> in my Rich Text (Redactor) editor?

Tags: redactor

I think this is some kind of a Redactor bug. This used to work just fine but within the last couple of Craft updates all of my words styled with the  within a paragraph tag ends up unstyled with a "" before the words that were styled with with this tag when saved, when loading a saved Entry Redactor loads it this way. It seems to happen only to the second styled  instances. I've contacted support but they didn't have an answer. I'm quite desperate to fix this as it's messing up our style guide Craft based site.

Here is an example shot.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `Clean up HTML` or `Purify HTML` boxes checked for the richtext field? What does the html you are entering in the richtext field look like? (what does the <> button show)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a Redactor bug to me as I can reproduce it on their demo site: http://imperavi.com/redactor/

I've created a support ticket with them reporting the issue.

Comment: Any updates on this Brad? I checked their website and bug is still there. They made updates since then. Does the ticket have any kind of tracking for eta?

Comment: Last I heard from them: `Thanks for this report. Looks like a bug, will investigate further and fix it asap.`. They don't have any sort of ticket tracking, but I'll ping them again.

Comment: @julzmon Actually looks like it's fixed in their latest release 10.1.2: `second and following instances of <code> didn’t receive proper visual formatting styles`. http://imperavi.com/redactor/log/ Will work on getting that into Craft.